# __call() function in CakePHP controllers?

Tags: php, cakephp, magic-methods

is `__call()` function available in CakePHP's controllers? I used this function in Zend Framework.

```
class UsersController extends AppController {
    function home(){
        /*some action*/
    }

    function __call($m, $p){
        print_r($m);
        print_r($p);
    }
}
```

I'm getting error like this:

> **Missing Method in UsersController**
>
> ```
> <?php
>
> class UsersController extends AppController {
>
>  var $name = 'Users';
>
>
>  function somemethodsnotincontoller() {
>
>  }
>
> }
> ?>
> ```
>
> for the URL **site.com/users/somemethodsnotincontoller**

Answer (score 6):

As many have pointed out here, __call() is a native PHP5 language "magic" method for catching calls to class methods that don't exist.

HOWEVER, Cake's core (I think it's the dispatcher) checks to see if the method exists first before calling it, and if it doesn't it renders the missing method error.

A solution might be for you to create your own AppError class, and handle the "catch all" method in there.

There is a limited amount of information in the cook book under [Error handling](http://book.cakephp.org/view/154/Error-Handling)

Answer (score 1):

Yes but it won't work because CakePHP invokes actions through `ReflectionMethod`

```
// CakePHP 2.4.3
// Controller.php
public function invokeAction(CakeRequest $request) {
    try {
        $method = new ReflectionMethod($this, $request->params['action']);
```

and methods called this way [are not processed](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#80619) by `_call`.

Answer (score 0):

Used it for what?

The __call() method is a construct in PHP that you can use from within classes that allow you to "catch" calls to methods that don't exist in the class explicitly.

From [PHP.net](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php):

> __call() is triggered when invoking inaccessible methods in an object
>   context.

So the answer is **yes**, as long as you are using PHP 5 or up.

Comment: This ignores the CakePHP context

Answer (score 0):

__call() is a language construct so it is available in all versions of php that support it.

Answer (score 0):

__call() is a magic-method of PHP, not any particular framework. It's impossible to answer this question without any context since __call() is defined in a particular object, not globally. Since CakePHP touts the fact that it is php4 compatible and __call() was introduced in php5 I would say no.

I looked at the production branch for Models and there is a call__() method, which looks like it tries to emulate PHP5's __call().

https://trac.cakephp.org/browser/branches/1.2.x.x/cake/libs/model/model.php?rev=4211#L437

---

**Edit** (Responding to comment):

Looking at Cake's base controller, there does not appear to be a 'catch-all' method available in controllers that mimics Zend's implementation of __call(). Your alternative to accomplish this would be to setup a route similar to cake's page route to catch all actions directed at a controller and send them to a single method.

Cake Trac for base controller:
https://trac.cakephp.org/browser/branches/1.2.x.x/cake/libs/controller/controller.php?rev=4211

Cake documentation on routing:
http://book.cakephp.org/view/46/Routes-Configuration

One of the examples in that documentation I referenced looks like something you can play with to accomplish what I mentioned above:

```
Router::connect(
    '/cooks/:action/*', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index')
);
```

Regardless of the given-action, always use the index action.

Comment: CakePHP does use __call, though.

Answer (score 0):

In CakePHP 3, you definitely can use `__call`, just ensure that the controller defines `isAction()`. For example:

```
public function isAction($action) {
    // To allow all actions to go to __call:
    return TRUE;
}

public function __call($name, $arguments) {
  //** your code called for every undefined action here **/
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`__call` is one of PHP 5's [magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) (see "[Method overloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.methods)" for more details).

If you are using PHP 5 *(and you are, if you are usinf Zend Framework)*, you can have a `__call` method in your classes, not depending on the framework you are working with.